# SQL Query for retrieving records having the same ID and Type but only separated by 3 minutes apart

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I am trying to write a query to retrieve the IDs from a table which looks like this:

| ID | TYPE | CREATED_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | start | 2021-11-01 21:43:48.0000000 |
| 1234 | start | 2021-11-01 21:44:40.0000000 |
| 1234 | end | 2021-11-04 15:27:50.0000000 |
| 4567 | start | 2021-09-02 20:12:40.0000000 |
| 4567 | start | 2021-09-02 23:01:11.0000000 |

Ideally I want the query to return the ID's which have  **2 or more** records of the **same type** and were created **less than 3 minutes** apart. So it should return ID 1234 because it has the 2 records of the type = start and created time less than 1 minute apart.
It should not return 4567 because the createdtime is 3 hours apart.

Comment: Don't know your process, but what about this scenario: ID 3456 Start at  21:00:00 and End at 21:01:00... and then Start at 21:02:00 and End at 21:05:00? In this case, the ID has two starts, but the first one should be ended by the first end event...

Comment: @Tyron78 the type could be anything and it doesn't need to end before another starts. Hope this made sense to you. Thanks :)

Comment: with the example you have given, you only want a result of "1234"....no other details required?

Comment: @GrahamH yes, i only want the query to return "1234".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is called DATA this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
FROM 
    DATA t1 JOIN
    DATA t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
    AND t1.TYPE = t2.TYPE 
    AND t1.CREATED_TIME <> t2.CREATED_TIME 
    AND (ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.CREATED_TIME, t2.CREATED_TIME))  < 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :)

Answer (score 2):

**Self-joining is inefficient.** You should use window functions for this

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      PrevVal = LAG(CREATED_TIME, 1, '19000101') OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Type ORDER BY CREATED_TIME)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE DATEADD(minute, 3, t.PrevVal) >= t.CREATED_TIME
GROUP BY ID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=46e4729dd5095e46f2038956192e72af)